# python selenium exception while fetching a url for scraping

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

The code runs fine before the try block. when I am fetching a url it gives exceptions .It only fetches first link and then crashes.
Please provide insights.I am getting all the links in a list but when I am fetching those urls in a for loop it crashes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException


baseUrl = 'http://www.thomassci.com/browse-by/suppliers'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(baseUrl)
mylinks= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ctl00') and contains(@id, 'ManufacturerName')]")

for links in mylinks:
  print links.get_attribute('href')
  datlnk=links.get_attribute('href')
  print links.text
  try:
   pghtml=driver.get(datlnk)
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  except:
      print('problem')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/thomas/thomastest.py", line 17, in <module>
    print links.get_attribute('href')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 102, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 404, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 195, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.46.0-py2.7.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: use implicit or explicit wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StaleElementReferenceException` means the WebElement you are trying to use is no longer valid. This happens when the DOM has changed (like moving to another url) or refreshed.

You can keep the urls in another list and iterate over it

```
mylinks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'ctl00') and contains(@id, 'ManufacturerName')]")
hrefs = []

for link in mylinks:
    hrefs.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

for href in hrefs:
    print href 
    datlnk = href
    #...
```

As a side note, `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` should be defined once, not every iteration of the loop.